# mov [reg], reg Not Working

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I can't seem to figure this out in x86. The program keeps crashing and my book says I can use [reg] to insert into memory so long as reg holds a location in memory:

```
.data
Counter BYTE 4;
Prompt BYTE "Enter an Integer: ", 0
UserInput DWORD 10 DUP(?)

.code
PromptUser PROC
     mov edx, OFFSET Prompt
     call WriteString
     ret
PromptUser ENDP

ReadUserInput PROC
     mov edx, OFFSET UserInput
     add edx, DWORD PTR Counter
     call ReadInt
     mov [edx], eax //ISSUE IS HERE
```

Even if I move the movs after the call to ReadInt, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What calling convention is `ReadInt` using?

Comment: The calling convention it's using is standard.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that ReadInt does not gobble up edx? Perhaps you should push edx on the stack before calling ReadInt and pop it after it returns.

Comment: I did and it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not going to end well:

```
Counter BYTE 4
add edx, DWORD PTR Counter
```

You've only got a `byte`, but you're treating it as if it was a `dword`. You'll end up adding not only the value of `Counter`, but the first 3 bytes of the `Prompt` string as well.

The simplest solution is to make `Counter` a `dword`. If you absolutely have to keep it a byte you can do something like:

```
movzx eax, BYTE PTR Counter
add edx,eax
```